Proxy working on cURL request but throwing a 407 with .NET 6
I'm trying to set a proxy for certain personal project but, until now, I haven't been able to achieve it.
The proxy urls have the format http://auser:apassword@domain:port, being each proxy in my proxy list a different url since they have different users and passwords.
I have tried to use them via a simple cURL request and, until now, they work fine. The cURL is something like
curl --proxy "http://auser:apassword@domain:port" "https://www.whateverwebsite.com" -k

But setting it within .NET 6 have been impossible so far, since it only throws a 407. The setup is more or less something like this:
private static IServiceCollection SetupProxy(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<MyWebClient>((serviceProvider, client) =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"www.whateverwebsite.com/");
        })
        .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(serviceProvider =>
        {
            var uri = new Uri(@"http://auser:apassword@domain:port");
            return new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Proxy = new WebProxy(uri),
                UseProxy = true,
                UseDefaultCredentials = true, //I have tried with and without this
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.Brotli
            };
        });

    serviceCollection.AddScoped<ILocalMyScraper>(s => new LocalMyScraper(s.GetService<MyWebClient>()));

    return serviceCollection;
}

If anybody need anything else I'll be delighted to add it here, but I think this is enough information (the project doesn't have almost anything else right now, just get a website and return some info).
I know that this could be something inherent to the proxy itself, but I don't know if there is some other setup that I have to do in .NET, or something that .NET sends that I'm not aware of, since it's weird that the cURL request works but in C# doesn't.
I have also tried to do the same thing with GO and works perfectly. So it should be something related to .NET.
For more information, I'm using .NET 6.
EDIT: I also tried to add the proxy credentials in the proxy object, like:
public class MyWebProxy : IWebProxy
{
    //...

    public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
    {
        var proxy = _proxyService.getProxy();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxy.Login) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxy.Password))
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxy.Login, proxy.Password);

        var url = @$"{host}:{port}";
        var uri = new Uri(url);

        return uri;
    }
}

But also the same thing.

What about setting the credentials via the Credential property of the WebProxy class and not putting it into the Uri?

I also tried that, but had the same error.

Mmmm, I'm starting to see the light at the end of the tunnel. If I add the credentials in the startup class, it works, but if I add the credentials in the CustomWebProxy object when retrieving the proxy, it throws that 407 so I understand that it only gets the credentials on starting.
In this case I would like to have the credentials on the proxy object since each proxy has it's own credentials and they are rotating proxies.
